Total params: 0 , on doing model.summary() keras
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(283, 100, input_length=56))
model.add(LSTM(150))
model.add(LSTM(150))
model.add(Dense(283, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

Tensorflow Version: 2.16.1,
Keras Version: 3.3.3 ,
Device - M3 pro macbook
I tried to build a LSTM model for text generation using a dummy dataset (had 282 unique words, checked with tokenizer), expected non zero params but the output is 0 params for each layer.

Read this: https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/, specially the "Specifying the input shape in advance" section.

Hi @firefistt_xdd,try with this line of code model.add(Input(shape=(56,), dtype='int32'))
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=283, output_dim=100))
model.add(LSTM(150, return_sequences=True)) . It will work for you if still facing any issue let me know ,thank you.

I faced the same issue, and was able to resolve it using the below code:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

# Ensure total_word and max_seq are defined correctly
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=total_word, output_dim=100, input_length=max_seq - 1))
model.build((None,max_seq)) # build the Embedding to inilizices the weight
model.add(LSTM(150, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100))  
model.add(Dense(total_word, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

Reason:
The reason our model works after adding model.build((None, max_seq)) is that the Embedding layer requires the input shape to be defined before it can initialize its weights. By calling model.build((None, max_seq)), you explicitly define the input shape, allowing the Embedding layer to initialize its weights properly.
In Keras, layers like Embedding can be added to a model without specifying the input shape. However, the layer's weights are not initialized until the model's input shape is known. Calling model.build() with the input shape as an argument triggers the weight initialization process. This is particularly useful when the input shape is dynamic or not known at the time of model definition.

Thank you, It was really helpful with the explanation!
